# Drop down menu items not aligning to parent

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble aligning the roll-over elements of the main menu on this website... http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2

The roll-over element should be in line with the parent, any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CSS attribute `position: relative` to the class `mainNav`

```
ul#nav li.mainNav {
  display: inline;
  padding-left:15px;
  position: relative;
}
(line 44 of style.css)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your css to this...

```
ul#nav li.mainNav {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```